# Python3, Jinja2, pre-compiled template, localization

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2, gettext

I have some old project .po/.mo files with placeholders like %s and it was used to translate python strings
But now I have these strings in jinja2 templates

Problem is that in .po file %s meanwhile in template {{ some_var }}

e.g I have template:

```
{% if some_var %}
Some text {{ some_var }}
{% else %}
Some another text {{ some_var1 }}
{% endif %}
```

I want to execute only conditions, filters, etc.
So I want to get string

```
Some another text {{ some_var1 }}
```

or

```
Some text {{ some_var }}
```

Next, I will get placeholders order and replace them with %s, use gettext and finally render the template

Any suggestions? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic way to do that but you can just use the old `.po` files. If your build system uses `msgmerge` for updating the `.po` files, the old translations will be reused but as "fuzzy" entries. You can then update the translations in the `.po` files.

You can also do that by hand. Assuming that your `.pot` file is `myproject.pot` and you want to merge that into the existing (old) file `ru.po` you do:

```
$ msgmerge --previous --verbose ru.po myproject.pot
```

If you wonder why you cannot do that automatically: You want to replace `%s` with something like `{{some_var}}`. Where should the information that the placeholder is `some_var` come from? In your old files, you always used `%s` and in the new files, the placeholders depend on the context.